# Pass a list/array in DB2 stored procedure

Tags: list, stored-procedures, db2

```
SELECT cc.clientid
FROM customer_client cc
GROUP BY cc.clientid
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN cc.customerid IN (4567, 5678) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*) 
   AND COUNT(*) = 2;
```

I'm calling this query in a Db2 stored procedure where in I've to pass the list of customer id - any working suggestion?

I've tried passing it as below in procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Find_Client_Customers (
    IN IN_CUSTIDS VARCHAR(1000),
    IN IN_CUST_COUNT INT)
```

but this is passing the list as a string.

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?

Comment: Platform is windows and DB2 11

Comment: "Array" implies some programming language; so, what programming language are you using to call the procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `string tokenizer`:

```
create function regexp_tokenize_number(
  source varchar(1024)
, pattern varchar(128))
returns table (seq int, tok bigint)
contains sql
deterministic
no external action
return
select seq, tok
from xmltable('for $id in tokenize($s, $p) return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
passing 
  source as "s"
, pattern as "p"
columns 
  seq for ordinality
, tok bigint path 'if (. castable as xs:long) then xs:long(.) else ()'
) t;

select *
from table(regexp_tokenize_number('123, 456', ',')) t;

SEQ TOK
--- ---
  1 123
  2 456
```

In your case:

```
SELECT cc.clientid
FROM customer_client cc
GROUP BY cc.clientid
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN cc.customerid IN 
(
select t.tok
from table(regexp_tokenize_number('4567, 5678', ',')) t
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*) 
AND COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Getting this error while running the above on db2 -- this works on db fiddle though. THE CLAUSES ARE MUTUALLY EXCLUSIVE. SQLCODE=-628, SQLSTATE=42613, DRIVER=4.17.36 SQL Code: -628, SQL State: 42613

Comment: @Ryan What doesn't work exactly? `CREATE FUNCTION`? It works on my 11.1 on Linux. It must work on Windows as well.

Comment: thanks for the help the answer is right - it runs fine on DB Fiddle but somehow not working for me on DB2 windows.. so I've accepted the answer. Now I'm getting AN XQUERY FUNCTION NAMED tokenize WITH 2 PARAMETERS IS NOT DEFINED IN THE STATIC CONTEXT. ERROR QNAME=err:XPST0017. SQLCODE=-16009, SQLSTATE=10506